# Magento 2: controller preference not working after setup:di:compile

Tags: magento2, overrides, dependency-injection, setup-di-compile, preference

I need to rewrite a couple of adminhtml controllers in Magento 2. I am using preference and my configuration in etc/di.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Widget\Controller\Adminhtml\Widget\LoadOptions"
                type="CustomModule\CustomWidgets\Controller\Widget\Adminhtml\Widget\WidgetLoadOptions" />

    <preference for="Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Wysiwyg\Images\OnInsert"
                type="CustomModule\CustomWidgets\Controller\Cms\Adminhtml\Wysiwyg\Images\WidgetOnInsert" />

</config>
```

After clear all generated folders (var/cache, var/di, var/generation) it works OK. The problem starts once I run `magento setup:di:compile` command. Compilation is executed successfully (tested in developer and production modes) but preference doesn't work (original Magento method is executed instead of mine).

Can someone help me? thanks in advance!

**EDITED:**

If someone has same issue, I have reported some time ago the issue in Magento 2 repository and they confirmed there was a bug:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5157

I will update the answer once they get it solved.

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong but I'm pretty sure it's **because those controllers are admin controllers and thus the corresponding `di.xml` should not be global.**

I reckon you should move your `di.xml` from `etc` to `etc/adminhtml`

Comment: Hi Raphael, thanks for answering, I have tested your suggestion but it doesn't work, also I have tested with some frontend controller and I have the same issue. Did you try to use preference + compilation with some controller and it worked? I tested in a clear Magento 2 installation and have the issue also

Comment: @joc_hhop pretty sure preference can work with almost any class